# JasperReports : (SubReport) The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I'm using JesperRports to create a report with `SubReport` inside of it, but it's not working and the code looks good.

The warning i get is : `The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null`.

Here is my full code :

MasterTeste.jrxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MasterTeste" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e976d12d-4c1b-4cfd-900a-6ac502f80b50">
    <parameter name="DS" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{lstCours}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nom" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nom]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="progres" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[progres]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[score]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lstCours" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lstCours]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="180" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="26" backcolor="#666666" uuid="06a43d96-317c-4a59-bfae-d014050e3955"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="6" width="65" height="20" uuid="7df685f6-8e54-4147-ac6e-52eae09577c0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Section : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="256" y="6" width="68" height="20" uuid="7cbd59f2-280d-4e8f-84db-5a7bf0425596"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Progres : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="434" y="6" width="60" height="20" uuid="b666bed5-48c7-4edb-ae70-5b582587e4f6"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Score :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="71" y="6" width="178" height="20" uuid="cb1fa244-3296-40d3-afd9-ee28d29c798d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="329" y="6" width="57" height="20" uuid="4d667ac4-cd25-4f1f-a1a5-5b354ccc00b9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{progres}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="500" y="6" width="55" height="20" uuid="3e771498-10a4-4f4c-9305-cd639de1b4e5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{score}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="36" width="555" height="140" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#99CCFF" uuid="33184f19-8225-428f-88ba-a488753fd445"/>
                <subreportParameter name="DS1">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{DS})]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["C:\\reports\\" + "teste.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Teste.jrxml (Subreport) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="hello" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="15289120-bdf0-4edd-905c-647999c3c0cc">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00FFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#C6C6C6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="2c012e5d-0895-4ef1-8b47-20fd8c6b281f">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="nom" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="introComp" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="lessComp" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="resumComp" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="quiz" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="progres" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="DS1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="151" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="1" y="4" width="555" height="140" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="1e15cf18-8adf-4bad-9339-04deb8240c82"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="5ccdd061-c1c3-46a0-bc92-af14bda9b14a">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="99" uuid="faddf5bb-759d-4efc-9a3e-9cf16b8cbda2">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="56" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Cours]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="56" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="103" uuid="8a8bc20b-f8b4-45a6-9cbd-68b4a7391426">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="90" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Introduction]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="74" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{introComp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="87" uuid="fde36038-294c-4987-bd03-734736ddb792">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="67" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Lesson]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="74" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lessComp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="51b5dbd4-1bf2-450f-ba8c-f75ea831860b">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="67" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Resume]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="74" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{resumComp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="87" uuid="657d2155-3e2f-4f41-ba0a-a17a76598491">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="67" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Quiz]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="56" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quiz}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="87" uuid="d36e39c4-8408-4f2f-865f-787aa3166a7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="35" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="67" height="20" uuid="795dac43-0ff0-482c-89a0-7dac3b27d513"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Progres]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="56" height="20" uuid="195d51a0-9e45-4201-ad67-d3026ce2e72c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{progres}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Java :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CoursRapport> coursRapports = new ArrayList<CoursRapport>();
        coursRapports.add(new CoursRapport("cours 1", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "100 %"));
        coursRapports.add(new CoursRapport("cours 2", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "100 %"));
        coursRapports.add(new CoursRapport("cours 3", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "Complet", "100 %"));

        SectionRapport sectRapport = new SectionRapport();

        sectRapport.setNom("Sect 1");
        sectRapport.setProgres("100%");
        sectRapport.setScore("80%");
        sectRapport.setLstCours(coursRapports);

        List<SectionRapport> lstSectionRapports = new ArrayList<SectionRapport>();
        lstSectionRapports.add(sectRapport);

        try{               
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\reports\\MasterTeste.jrxml");   
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstSectionRapports));      // new JREmptyDataSource()
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\ressources\\teste.pdf");
            System.out.println("HelloJasper.pdf has been generated!");
        } catch (JRException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

When i used sample report it was working fine, but now the `subreport` part comes empty with the warning i mentioned above, so maybe i didn't implement the `subreport` correctly ?.

Answer (score 2):

Set whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" in the subreport (on the jasperReport element) and move the table element to the title or summary band.

Alternatively, you can pass new JREmptyDataSource() as data source expression for the subreport from the master report.